# How can I easily split a CSV into two Excel worksheets with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, csv, powershell-2.0

I recently found out that PowerShell can be used to write Excel documents. The first use I thought of for this was to (at least partially) automate parsing of some CSV reports that I regularly have to work with.

The basic job I need to do goes something like this:

1. Create an Excel workbook with two worksheets.
2. Copy the column headers from the CSV file to Row 1 on both sheets.
3. For each row in the CSV that meets a certain condition (e.g.: value in column R equals "Don't put in Sheet 1") append the row to Excel worksheet 2.
4. Each row in the CSV that is not destined for Excel worksheet 2 should be appended to Excel worksheet 1.

Step 1 is simple enough - I've found several guides online to help me get started there. I'm also confident I can handle the conditional logic required for steps 3 & 4 on my own, based on past PowerShell experience. The problem I'm having a hard time finding a solution for is writing all the data into the sheets.

I haven't actually written any Excel-generating PowerShell scripts just yet, but every guide that I've seen only seems to include instructions for writing individual cells - not entire rows at once. Is there an easier way to do this?

Some things I'd be interested in, if they exist:

- Some means of copying an entire row from a CSV file to an Excel worksheet without having to loop through individual cells in the row.
- Some way of copying an entire row from one CSV file to another without having to loop through individual cells, plus a command (or reasonably short script) to import a whole CSV file into an Excel Worksheet.
- Last resort: A for loop (or similarly short script block) to be used in place of a write-entire-row method. This should be able to determine where to stop copying cells in a row without having to go all the way to the last column (I think it's XFD these days), while gracefully handling empty cells in the middle of a row.

Aside from figuring out the above, the real hard part of my script is going to be making sure it can work *efficiently* on source CSV files that may be thousands (possibly tens of thousands) of rows long.

The final script will need to be compatible with Windows 7, PowerShell 2.0, and Excel 2010.